# Please don't edit away all the questions in a post

Tags: discussion, editing

Although the questions in the original version of [this post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/45628/revisions) were an implicit request for advice which should probably have been closed as "cannot be generalized to others", there was at least something approaching a question in the post. Unfortunately, the post was edited to remove this implicit question and the post is now, instead, on the brink of being closed as "Unclear what you're asking." The cumulative effect seems rather unfair on the original asker: we delete the question and then appear to be dinging her for not asking a question. (Related phenomenon: [Motorist given parking ticket after council contractors moved her legally parked car](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-manchester-32686498).)

Please be careful when editing that you don't remove all the questions from a post. If the only questions there are unsuitable for the site, we should just close the post for that reason.

I'm not posting this to criticize the person who made the edit, or the people who voted to close. But I do think we should be careful not to do this kind of thing.

<sub>Ironically, there's no question in this post, either.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

There was never really a viable question there. It was (and remains) a long, rambling, "here's my [boyfriend's] story, what do you think?"

The edits were pretty much pointless. The question should have just been put on hold straight away, for the OP to to edit down to a specific answerable question.